# find close elements in numpy recarray

Tags: python, numpy, recarray

I am trying to find all the values from `numpy` record array `no1` which are closest to values in rec array `no2` (record arrays have different number of values)

Lets say `no1` has fields:

`('electrode', 'i4'), ('no_of_interest_time', 'i4'), ('time', 'f8')`

where `time` is time of specific event and `no_of_interest_time` indexes events that should be analyzed separately. Each of the events  is given such a number and multiple events may share the same number. `electrode` holds the index of an electrode in which event was recorded (location).

`no2` has the same fields but holds different events.

For each event in recarray `no2`, I want to find closest event from recarray `no1` of the same type (`no_of_interest_time`) and location (`electrode`).

The way I can solve it using for loops would look like this,  but I am looking for much more elegant solution:

```
import numpy as np

i_recarr1 = np.argsort(recarray1, order=['electrode', 'no_of_interest_time', 'time'])
recarr1_sorted = recarray1[i_recarr1]

i_recarr2 = np.argsort(recarray2, order=['electrode', 'no_of_interest_time', 'time'])
recarr2_sorted = recarray2[i_recarr2]

closest_events = recarr2_sorted.copy()

for electr in np.unique(recarr2_sorted['electrode']):
    # use only this electrode
    recarr1_record = recarr1_sorted[recarr1_sorted['electrode'] == electr]
    recarr1_record = recarr2_sorted[recarr2_sorted['electrode'] == electr]

    for interest in np.unique(recarr2_record['no_of_interest_time']):
        # use only this time of interest
        recarr1_interest = recarr1_sorted[recarr1_record['no_of_interest_time'] == interest]
        recarr2_interest = recarr1_sorted[recarr1_record['no_of_interest_time'] == interest]

        for idx, event2 in np.enumerate(recarr2_interest['time']):
            # loop through every event to find neighbours
            selected_idx = (np.abs(recarr1_interest['time']-event2)).argmin()
            closest_events[(closest_events['electrode'] == electr) & 
                           (closest_events['no_of_interest_time']) == interest][idx] = recarr1_interest['time'][selected_idx]

inverse_i = np.argsort(i_recarr2)       
closest_events[inverse_i]
```

I will appreciate any advice. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
closest_events = []
for t in no1:
    #sort
    i = np.argsort(np.abs(t['time']-no2['time']))
    # select only events with the same no_of_interest_time and electrode
    i = i[(no2['electrode']==t['electrode']) &
          (no2['no_of_interest_time']==t['no_of_interest_time'])]
    closest = i[0] if len(i)>0 else np.nan
    closest_events.append(closest)
```

The idea is that for each event in `no1` you first calculate distances between this event and all events in `no2`. Next, you sort the distances from the shortest to longest and store the indices (`i` in the function). From `i` you select only the elements of specific type and location and finally you take first of the remaining indices (if the array is empty, return `NaN`).